# Read variable length string from binary file

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have a binary file which consists firstly o a header listing the coloumn types and then the data. A typical example looks like this:

`8Byte for a double`, `8Byte double`, `4Byte for a int32`.

This sequence is repeated several times (Between 10k and 20M times).
This can be easily read with:

`numpy.fromfile(file_id, dtype = (('A': '<f8'), ('A': '<f8'), ('A': '<f8', count = n_repetitions)`

But know I have a sequence like:

`8Byte for a double`, `4Byte for a int32 defining the next char field length`, `char's of lenght defined before`,`8Byte double`, `4Byte for a int32`

Due to this I cannot use `S#`, since the field length is not the same for each element in the list. Is there a better way to read the file rather than iterate line, by line? The solution doesn't necessarily have to be `numpy` but should be callable by `python`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [BitString](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring):

```
# example taken from [illuminate][2] 
from bitstring import BitString

bs = BitString(bytes=open(bitstring_or_filename, 'rb').read())
recordlen = bs.read('uintle:8')  # length of each record

# 206 * 8 = 1648 record  length in bits
for i in range(0,((bs.len) / (recordlen * 8))):
    # ....
```

Comment: I guess my wording of the problem is a bit confusing. Sorry for that. the problem I have is that the char length for each entry is different for each instance. When read the string is of the form `str = ('bla', 'blabla', 'bl', ...)`